# Throwing error while creating tables in SQL

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, debugging

I am currently executing a code, trying to create tables:

```
cur.executescript('''
    CREATE TABLE User(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE ,
    name TEXT, email_id TEXT);

    CREATE TABLE Courses(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    course_name TEXT);

    CREATE TABLE Member(
        user_id INTEGER, course_id INTEGER, role INTEGER)/*student-0 teacher 1*/
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, course_id);
''')
```

It gives me this error:

File "E:\python_folder_practice_app_programming\SQLite\beginner_pro_db\beginner_pro_db.py", line 18, in 
**cur.executescript('''
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "PRIMARY": syntax error**

Can someone help me debug this?

Comment: Please try using one create statement per execute call.

Comment: Ha! it worked, but executescript() function does let us execute out multiple statements. why didn't it work with multiples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problematic statement

```
CREATE TABLE Member(
    user_id INTEGER, course_id INTEGER, role INTEGER)/*student-0 teacher 1*/
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, course_id);
```

Your `primary key` constraint should be inside the parens (and separated by comma)

Like this (I've broken it into several lines for readability)

```
CREATE TABLE Member(
    user_id INTEGER, 
    course_id INTEGER, 
    role INTEGER, /*student-0 teacher 1*/
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, course_id)
);
```

See examples here https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/